# Core Animation loop without gaps

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation, cabasicanimation

[image]

Assuming I animate the central orange "HELLO" from left to right using the code below

**Q:** How can one animate the following ticker so it will look like the view "HELLO" is moving endlessly without gaps or jumps. (imagine it like a stock market ticker...)

```
-(void)animate:(UIView *)thisView
    {
        CABasicAnimation *moveView;
        moveView            = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position.x"];
        moveView.byValue    = @(self.view.frame.size.width);
        moveView.duration   = 3.0;
        moveView.removedOnCompletion = YES;
        moveView.fillMode   = kCAFillModeRemoved;
        moveView.autoreverses = NO;
         moveView.repeatCount = 10;
        [[thisView layer] addAnimation:moveView forKey:@"x"];
 }
```

Comment: Do you want it to say `lloHelloHelloHel` or... `llo        He`? i.e. when You say no gaps what do you mean? Do you want a single "Hello" label to fill the width but have no gaps to the next "Hello" label? Or should the "Hello" label only be the width of the contents of it?

Comment: Also, I think you're animation direction should be the other way. Having it the way the arrow is pointing will mean read the labels backwards.

Comment: Hey @Fogmeister , the "Hello" view is the width of the content view, I updated the image above to make it clearer.
The HELLO view is a single view the size of self.view.width, the label inside it is just for illustrating the problem.

Comment: OK, just adding an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, to do this you will need two labels. Also, I'll be using block based animation. The animation method you are using is very old and discouraged since iOS4.

**Anyway...**

First you need to set your view up like this...

```
               | Screen width  |
               |               |
[    Label    ]|[    Label    ]|
```

The two labels should be in a single view that is double the width of the screen.

So the frame of the `containerView` will start something like...

```
CGRect containerFrame = CGRectMake(-320, 0, 640, 44);
```

Then you can do this for the animation...

```
- (void)animateLabels
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:3.0
                          delay:0.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                     animations:^{
                         // animate the container frame to the right 320 points
                         containerView.frame = CGRectOffset(containerView.frame, 320, 0);
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         // move it back to where it started
                         containerView.frame = CGRectOffset(containerView.frame, -320, 0);
                         [self animateLabels];
                     }];
}
```

This will slide the two labels over to the right and then quickly put them back and start animating them again. It will give the illusion of having an infinite row of labels sliding across the screen.

Comment: Thanks @Fogmeister, I agree that this code works yet I was looking for something else. 
1. I would like to control the timing and other animatic elements, CA seems to have more to offer.
2. I am intending a heavy animation on this ticker, I was told that CA would be a better path opposing to the uiview animation, what is your take on that
3. the delay trick will work, but isn't there a nicer more elegant way?

Nevertheless, thanks for a the simple solution, it may be a help to someone.

Comment: This is core animation. This is how you create complex animations. You can even do key frame animations and spring animations. Etc... The method you are using should not be used. This method replaced it about 4 years ago.

Comment: fair enough. back to the drawing board.